# Page number in multiple pages document in Acrobat Reader

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

Using ApacheFop 2.2 I get a multi-page document. The document consists of parts, each of which begins with the page number 1.
After the formation of PDF there is a need to print the 5th page of the document. When specifying a page for printing, the 11th page of the document will be printed (it is the 5th page in its part).
How to generate PDF correctly, so that the 5th page was exactly the 5 th page of the document, and not part of it?

fo:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  font-size="30pt">
    <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="page">
            <fo:region-body region-name="body" margin-top="22mm" margin-bottom="34mm"/>
            <fo:region-after region-name="footer" extent="31mm"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="blank-page">
            <fo:region-body region-name="body-blank" margin-top="22mm" margin-bottom="34mm"/>
            <fo:region-after region-name="footer" extent="31mm"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
        <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="document">
            <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
                <fo:conditional-page-master-reference blank-or-not-blank="not-blank" master-reference="page"/>
                <fo:conditional-page-master-reference blank-or-not-blank="blank" odd-or-even="even" master-reference="blank-page"/>
            </fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
        </fo:page-sequence-master>
    </fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="document" initial-page-number="1" force-page-count="end-on-even">
        <fo:static-content flow-name="footer">
            <fo:block>
                <fo:page-number/>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:static-content>
        <fo:flow flow-name="body">
            <fo:block break-after="page">Text1</fo:block>
        </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="document" initial-page-number="1" force-page-count="end-on-even">
        <fo:static-content flow-name="footer">
            <fo:block>
                <fo:page-number/>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:static-content>
        <fo:flow flow-name="body">
            <fo:block break-after="page">Text3</fo:block>
            <fo:block break-after="page">Text4</fo:block>
            <fo:block break-after="page">Text5</fo:block>
        </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="document" initial-page-number="1" force-page-count="end-on-even">
        <fo:static-content flow-name="footer">
            <fo:block>
                <fo:page-number/>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:static-content>
        <fo:flow flow-name="body">
            <fo:block break-after="page">Text7</fo:block>
            <fo:block break-after="page">Text8</fo:block>
            <fo:block break-after="page">Text9</fo:block>
            <fo:block break-after="page">Text10</fo:block>
            <fo:block break-after="page">Text11</fo:block>
        </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

[AdobeReader Page Numbering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFThf.png)

Comment: Please explain your image. Page numbering shown in the image is correct. Are you asking for incorrect numbering?

Comment: When using FOP 0.95, the numbering of pages in the document in the Acrobat Reader is single. When using FOP 1 and above, the numbering is double: page numbering in part + page numbering in the document.
If you select, for example, the 5th page of the document, the 11th page (the 5th page in the part of the document) will be printed.  The error is that in a large document with such a numbering it is impossible to select the required range. If you generate the described  FO-file and print from pages 5 to 11, only the 11th page will be printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, a page number is not the best way to tell a user which page to print, because it's going to be confusing anyway. You might have more than one page with page number 5 in your document, for example.
Alternatives:

- on the first page of the document, include a hyperlink to the page that has to be printed
- create a bookmark for the page that must be printed

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Links in the document work correctly, there are bookmarks and a table of content. Problems occur when the user tries to print a part of the document on the printer by opening a document in the Acrobat Reader. In another application, for example, NitroPDF problem does not arise. But Acrobat Reader is by default the standard application that is worth all users.

Comment: It looks like you can edit the page numbering in Acrobat to remove this behavior:  http://www.adobepress.com/articles/article.asp?p=1998556&seqNum=4

Comment: Thanks for link, Adobe Acrobat allows to change page numbering. Not automatic solution, but it works for me